# Accessing a certain attribute's value within a <tr> with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am scraping a web page and I am finding trouble accessing the value of an attribute within a `<tr>` tag in the OuterHTML of a node.

```
<tr data-descr="Revit+SA+regression+-+Obj" data-ids="2571302">
```

The above HTML contains the attribute `data-ids` which I am trying to get the value of.
Below is the code for accessing the web page (I would like to point out that I am deeply sorry for the lack of a reproductible example due to the web page not being accessible to the public) and reaching the node containing certain keywords that I wanted to investigate.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load("WebPageIsPrivate");
HtmlNode[] nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
            .Where(x => x.InnerHtml.Contains("Revit") & x.InnerHtml.Contains("regression")).ToArray();
```

At this point, I figured that I can use `nodes.OuterHtml.ToString()` to get the HTML above. However, this would mean that I'd have to replace the string's characters until I only have the `2571302` (in this example) left. I am wondering whether there's an easier way of getting to that value.

Please let me know if the post is not clear enough to the reader and requires more details - I will do my best to provide them. Documentation on this subject is also highly welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: You can access the attributes of individual nodes like this: `var ids = node.Attributes["data-ids"].Value;`

Comment: Yeah, I just found out now! Thanks for your answer, anyway. Off-topic question now; should I delete the post (because I feel like I just didn't look through the internet enough to find an answer prior to this) or keep it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
{
   x.Add(item.Attributes["data-ids"].Value);
}
```

This did the job.